# How can I git fetch --unshallow in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I am integrating SonarQube into Jenkins. We currently use shallow clones because our repository is slow to clone entirely given a large binary files in history. SonarQube needs to run `git blame` which apparently doesn't work on shallow clones. I need a workaround, but I can't change the global Jenkins config (it would slow down all builds).

Situation:

`checkout scm` works with no arguments.

`sh 'git fetch --unshallow` gets an error as it doesn't have credentials.

I've tried this monstrosity to customize the arguments to checkout scm:

```
checkout scm: [
    $class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [
        [url: env.repoURL, credentialsId: 'GitHubEnterprise']
    ], extensions: [
        [$class: 'CheckoutOption', timeout: 60],
        [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: true,
            reference: '/var/lib/gitchcache/reference.git',
            shallow: false, timeout: 60]
    ], branches: [
        [name: branch]
    ]
], remoteName: "origin", poll: false, clearWorkspace: true
```

But I get this error:

```
> git rev-parse PR-42^{commit} # timeout=10

Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository
and branch configuration for this job.
```

Reported issues seem to center around failing to provide "Name of repository":

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21845
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29520
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37144

I was trying to build a Pull Request and it did not have the refspec for the change. I don't know why it couldn't infer that, but it doesn't.

Here's what worked to address that first part:

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
               userRemoteConfigs: [
                       [url: env.GIT_URL,
                        refspec: "+refs/pull/${prNumber}/head:refs/remotes/origin/${branch}",
                        credentialsId: 'GitHubEnterprise']
               ],
               extensions: [
                       [$class: 'CloneOption',
                        shallow: false,
                        timeout: 60]
               ],
               branches: [
                       [name: branch]
               ]
]
```

The checkout works, the build works, but I still get a shallow checkout...

```
INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
INFO: 1 files to be analyzed
WARN: Shallow clone detected, no blame information will be provided. You can convert to non-shallow with 'git fetch --unshallow'.
INFO: 0/1 files analyzed
WARN: Missing blame information for the following files:
WARN:   * src/main/java/com/example/Example.java
```

Here's what I have under Project - GitHub Organization in Jenkins configuration:
[image: Advanced clone behaviours]

Here's what I want for a specific build step: `checkout scm`, but with the shallow "unchecked" in code.

How can I git fetch --unshallow in Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the git jenkins plugin as of version git-4.0.0-beta3. [There is no support or mention whatsoever](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/search?q=unshallow&unscoped_q=unshallow) in the source for the `unshallow` parameter of `git fetch`.

What you can do is leave out your git jenkins plugin option as is: shallow first fetch so it's faster.

Then you have some options:

- In the execute shell for the build you can run the unshallow procedure by using `git` directly, not via the plugin.
- If this would slow down too many builds, have a prerun step before SonarQube go into the workspace and run the unshallow procedure. This can be done via a Groovy script among other things.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I appreciate it. I get authentication failures with `sh 'git fetch --unshallow'`. Is there a trick to run the Git command line with credentials from checkout scm?

Comment: You might need to add the public key of the user doing the git commands to the allowed keys in your repository.

Comment: See [JENKINS-28335](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335).